# Информация о клиенте

Tags: php

Кто знает скрипт **PHP** который выводит информацию о клиенте?

IP адрес, браузер, страна, ОС.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эту информацию можно получить с какого-то сервиса, к примеру **ipinfo.io**

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}/json"));
echo var_dump($deatals); // Покажет всю полученную информацию
echo $details->city; // Покажет город
```

Ну а по поводу OC хорошо написано вот тут [Get operating system info with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18070154/get-operating-system-info-with-php)